# USB-C socket broke on an LG monitor. Can I hard-wire a USB-A cable?

Tags: usb-c

I have a mess on my hands.

LG monitors have these absolutely horrible USB-C plug connectors which are surface mount and flex so all the pads rip off (if you have one of these monitors, solder the connector to the RF shield before it's too late). I desoldered mine hoping I could patch all the pads and reflow it, but one of the pins on the connector itself has fatigued off and these are LG-specific connectors that no competent company would ever use.

This monitor has other inputs I can use, but seemingly (based on very limited online clues), ONLY the USB-C connector can be used to do a firmware update. It has USB-A plugs but they're only active as a hub for the USB-C host and are basically worthless.

Would it be possible to temporarily hard wire a USB-A cable to the board to perform this update? All the documentation I've seen only refers to USB-A to USB-C USB 3.0 cables which need a bunch of connections to figure out orientation and I was hoping for something simpler.

[image: board]

[image: socket]

[image: TUSB8041i]

Comment: That connector will still work if you repair the traces. All of the USB 2 pins are there (probably all you need) and the usb3 will still work in one orientation.

Comment: How would the connector work if one of the pins is busted? I think that's the B3 pin? Which pins are necessary for the USB-A cable to work?

Comment: You only need that pin to do USB 3 in one orientation. On the other orientation it would be used for the optional 2x2 mode which cables don't have to support. I don't know the minimum to update firmware, but I'd start with the USB 2 pins, PWR and GND.

Comment: This would be a heck of a lot easier if I didn't have to use this POS socket. The pins are embedded in between the posts so doing this experimentally one at a time is not feasible.

Comment: I'm going to try a data-only patch to USB_DP_UP and USB_DM_UP 

Comment: Patched in a USB cable and it didn't work. Serves me right for buying an LG monitor. Never again

Comment: At very least you must attach ground as well as data. Otherwise there is no return path for current. I still think the easiest option is to repair the 4 USB 2 pins on that connector.

Answer (score 1):

USB-A is not USB-C.

Adafruit makes [a USB-C socket breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4396).

[image]

I would just get my magnifying glass and tack the needed wires to the LG board.

Then I'd go to town with wood and epoxy and come up with a chassis mount for that board.

They also make chassis mount USB-C connectors, but most of them provide a USB-A plug on the other end, which is not adequate for your requirements (since you tried it).